# impossible to remove a ppa

Tags: apt, xubuntu, ppa

I just upgraded to xubuntu 18.04 LTS from 16.04, and I have an issue while trying to remove old obsolete PPAs :

```
nicolas@nicolas-UX530UX:~$ sudo ls /etc/apt/sources.list.d
deadsnakes-ubuntu-ppa-xenial.list          dropbox.list.save            nilarimogard-ubuntu-webupd8-xenial.list.distUpgrade  skype-stable.list          teamviewer.list.save
deadsnakes-ubuntu-ppa-xenial.list.distUpgrade  google-chrome.list           nilarimogard-ubuntu-webupd8-xenial.list.save         skype-stable.list.distUpgrade
deadsnakes-ubuntu-ppa-xenial.list.save         google-chrome.list.distUpgrade       ondrej-ubuntu-php-xenial.list                skype-stable.list.save
dropbox.list                       google-chrome.list.save          ondrej-ubuntu-php-xenial.list.distUpgrade        teamviewer.list
dropbox.list.distUpgrade               nilarimogard-ubuntu-webupd8-xenial.list  ondrej-ubuntu-php-xenial.list.save           teamviewer.list.distUpgrade
```

Here we can see that I have the PPA

> deadsnakes-ubuntu-ppa-xenial.list

So I try to delete it somehow :

```
nicolas@nicolas-UX530UX:~$ sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:deadsnakes-ubuntu-ppa-xenial.list/ppa
        Cannot add PPA: 'ppa:~deadsnakes-ubuntu-ppa-xenial.list/ubuntu/ppa'.
        ERROR: '~deadsnakes-ubuntu-ppa-xenial.list' user or team does not exist.
nicolas@nicolas-UX530UX:~$ sudo ppa-purge ppa:deadsnakes-ubuntu-ppa-xenial.list/ppa
Updating packages lists
PPA to be removed: deadsnakes-ubuntu-ppa-xenial.list ppa
Warning:  Could not find package list for PPA: 
deadsnakes-ubuntu-ppa-xenial.list ppa
```

Any idea of why I am not able to remove it?

Comment: I even removed it with GUI, and it is well removed from list of GUI but not from /etc/apt/sources.list.d

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can PPAs be removed?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/307/how-can-ppas-be-removed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using,

```
sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
```

It's works to me.